# Convert byte array to .wav java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I have a web service that returns an array of bytes and my intention is to convert said array to a .wav in the client (a handheld such as Blackberry). However I really have no idea of how to do that, I tried just making an FileOutputStream but of course that wouldn't play. So I am once again without knowing what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: there area number of ways for the data to be corrupted between the web service and the media player on the device. You might want to give us more details about exactly what you're doing, including the code that runs on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are LOTS of .WAV formats, here's some documentation:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV
- http://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ (note endian changes)
- http://www.lightlink.com/tjweber/StripWav/WAVE.html

It's not just a stream of data bytes, but it's close...  Just a bit of header and you should be good.

I suppose you could also use something like http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/spi/AudioFileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

```
*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package bemukan.voiceRecognition.speechToText;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

/**
 *
 * @author MuhammedYC
 */
public class SplitAudio {
    private int BUFFER_LENGTH=1024;
    private double startTime;
    private double endTime;
    private File sourceFile;
    public SplitAudio(File sourceFile,int startTime,int endTime){
        this.startTime=startTime;
        this.endTime=endTime;
        this.sourceFile = sourceFile;
        AudioInputStream inputAIS = null;
        try {
            inputAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sourceFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(inputAIS);
            long totalMicroSecond = clip.getMicrosecondLength();
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {

        }
    }
    public void splitAudio(){

        File outputFile = new File("a.wav");
        AudioFileFormat fileFormat = null;
        try {
            fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(sourceFile);
            AudioFileFormat.Type targetFileType = fileFormat.getType();
                AudioFormat audioFormat = fileFormat.getFormat();


                AudioInputStream inputAIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sourceFile);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int nBufferSize = BUFFER_LENGTH * audioFormat.getFrameSize();
                byte[] abBuffer = new byte[nBufferSize];
                while (true) {

                    int nBytesRead = inputAIS.read(abBuffer);

                    if (nBytesRead == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    baos.write(abBuffer, 0, nBytesRead);
                }
                /* Here's the byte array everybody wants.
                 */
                byte[] abAudioData = baos.toByteArray();

               // double baslangic = abBuffer.length * oranBaslangic;
               // double bitis = abBuffer.length * oranSon;

                byte[] splittedAudio = new byte[(int) (endTime - startTime)];
                for (int i = 0; i < (int) (endTime- startTime); i++) {
                    splittedAudio[i] = abAudioData[i + (int) startTime];
                }
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(splittedAudio);
                AudioInputStream outputAIS = new AudioInputStream(bais, audioFormat,
                        splittedAudio.length / audioFormat.getFrameSize());

                AudioSystem.write(outputAIS, targetFileType, outputFile);

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }
}
```